# How are percentage fields evaluated in process builder?

Tags: process-builder, percent

I'm having trouble figuring out how percent fields, specifically formula percent fields, are evaluated in criteria for process builder.  We have a basic process using the "Conditions are met" criteria.

[image: percentage as a decimal]

The above criteria stopped working at some point - I don't know exactly when. I know salesforce pushed out an update that changed the way percent values were handled in process builder: [trust percent values...](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_percentage.htm)

Also, based on everything I've read, percent fields should be referred to as field value / 100 (e.g. 90% = 0.9).

When troubleshooting this issue, I tried changing the value to 50 instead of .5, which worked.  I can't find any documentation anywhere saying this is how it should work.  I'm afraid to go through all my processes and update them with this logic if there's something I'm missing?  Should we reference percent fields as the whole value that's displayed in a percent field moving forward?

Also, for testing, I had the process update two test fields with the percent paid formula field value in the condition.  One was a number field, the other a percent field.  The process updated both fields with the same value - e.g. if the percent paid formula field was 40%, it would put 40 in both the number and percent fields.
[image: test field values]

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in the back of my mind when studying for my Admin exam, fields were stored a numbers and SF converted them to decimals when using. So 45% was stored as 45. I tried the University of Google and did not find an answer. Just a hunch on my part.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is an official answer but based on my extensive testing, percentage fields are evaluated differently depending on whether or not you use a formula in process builder (Setting the Criteria for Executing Actions* to Formula evaluates to true) vs using the Conditions are met criteria.

If you are using a formula, you use the percent number / 100, e.g. 50% is 0.5

If you are using the conditions are met option, you use the number that you see in the percent / formula percent field, e.g. 50% is 50.

Comment: isn't this similar (i.e. consistent with) filter expression in listviews or reports versus custom formula fields or validation rules?